# How to seed a one file only with sequelize-cli?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

sequqlize-cli db:seed:all is working fine, but how to seed only one file? Tried to db:seed:[name-that-i-gave-with-create-command] and db:seed:[full-path-to-seed-file.js] but it doesnt work. It outputs nothing. Docs say **sequelize db:seed Run specified seeder** But how to do that?

Comment: as far as i know, It is not working (yet).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To run a specific seed indicate `--seed <seed_file_nams.js>`:

```
sequelize db:seed --seed my_seeder_file.js
```

Answer (score 10):

We can launch a specific seeder via **npx sequelize-cli** with the following command :

```
npx sequelize-cli db:seed --seed my-seeder-file.js
```

Answer (score 4):

To run a specific seed indicate file name *(seeder_file.js)*, also seeders directory and config path:

```
sequelize db:seed --seed seeder_file.js --config src/config/db.js --seeders-path src/seeders
```

Answer (score 0):

To run all files

```
npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all
```

To run specific file

```
npx sequelize db:seed --seed temp-seeder.js
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some lines that We need to have after making the seeding file:

```
  let data = JSON.parse(await fs.readFileSync('./category.json', 'utf-8'))
data.forEach(element => {
  element.createdAt = new Date()
  element.updatedAt = new Date()
})

await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Categories', data, {})
```

and put the BulkDelete in async down.

```
  await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Categories', data, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

To run all seed file with config :
`npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all --config  <your_config_file_location>`
Example(which work for me):
`npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all --config  api/config/config.js`

If add file name
`npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all <file_name> --config  api/config/config.js`